# Chris Ingram link is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com

In the [Team Page](https://stackexchange.com/about/team), the link for Chris Ingram leads to a 404 Page Not Found here on MSE.

The link is https://meta.stackexchange.com/accounts/5418119 while it should actually be https://stackexchange.com/users/5418119/chris-ingram. (or https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/276270/chris-ingram but all others points to the network profile)

Surely he's really miserable about it and wonder "why nobody view my profile?!" :)

Comment: What a way to be told you're no longer with the company

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong link there, indeed.

Fixed, but the page is cached, so a bit before that shows up.

Comment: Ninja fix! Cheers, but now he's last... hope he won't come after me with a smiting stick for being mocked up as the "greenest" employee. :-D

Comment: @Sha - yeah, something was borked on the admin page, but I fixinated that now. Another cache invalidation and he is golden.

Comment: Another tiny bug, possible typo in the [new blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/): "hott new “about” page" - is the double "t" by design?

Comment: @Sha - probably not... first couple of comments mentioned that ;)